Decrease the number of brokers in Kafka AWS MSK
I am trying to decrease the number of brokers in AWS MSK
When i go to Edit number of brokers, and try to decrease it by one, i get the following error:
In the table below, AZs with an error status have user partitions on every broker. To remove brokers in a cluster, reassign partitions so that each AZ has brokers without user partitions. Once reassigned, allow 5 minutes after status update to save changes

I tried to follow the mentioned steps by running the following commands from an EC2 connected to same VPC with MSK
./kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server "xxxxxxxx" --list

exported the data in formatted json file named topics.json
Then i run the following command:
./kafka-reassign-partitions.sh --bootstrap-server "xxxxxxxxxxx" --topics-to-move-json-file topics.json --broker-list 1,2 --generate

saved the out put using standard output redirection to: reassignment-file.json
finally i ran:
./kafka-reassign-partitions.sh --bootstrap-server "xxxxxxxxx" --reassignment-json-file reassignment-file.json --execute

But when i run
 ./kafka-reassign-partitions.sh --bootstrap-server  "xxxxxxxxx" --reassignment-json-file reassignment-file.json --verify

I find it always stop like this:
Reassignment of partition xxxxxx is completed.
Reassignment of partition xxxx is completed.
Reassignment of partition xxxx is completed.
Reassignment of partition xxxx is completed.
Clearing broker-level throttles on brokers 5,1,6,2,3,4
Clearing topic-level throttles on topics    

But still cannot decrease the number:

